# How to change value in button Field for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send Textbox value to other page.
I am tring many times to do that thing:

ASPX PAGE: Defalut2.aspx

```
 <%Post p = new Post();
      List<Post> lp = new List<Post>();
      for (int i = 0; i < lp.Count; i++)
      {
          Session["id"] = lp[i].postID;//Get The Id post
          %>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
          <%
          //I Have a PostID and i need to call to method
           //Now I need to save   lp[i].postID In Something for to Use in Default2.aspx.cs Page
          //I want to create a new response by post id


      } %>Default2.aspx.cs Page


      } %>'
```

Defalt2.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Responses p = new Responses();
    Cubers c = new Cubers();
   p.InsertResponseUser("Admin",int.Parse(Session["id"].ToString()),"xxxxx",DateTime.Now);
    //method add response to post by username,id post, description,date time ;


}
```

The problem is I can't add new comment to my post becaue I can't save and find my `postID`. Now I need to find a way to save the id in something. for I call a method from defalut2.aspx.cs. I need to use post id.

Comment: Do you want to send ID to some other page ?

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: i want to send id to code aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do it this way, you could use repeater to bind your List as below 

ASPX PAGE: Defalut2.aspx

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptPosts" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>

        </HeaderTemplate>   
        <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                     CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'/>
            </td>
              <br />
          </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Defalt2.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<testWebApp.Post> lp = new List<testWebApp.Post>();

            Post p = new Post();
            p.ID = 1;
            Post p2 = new Post();
            p2.ID = 22;
            lp.Add(p);
            lp.Add(p2);

            rptPosts.DataSource = lp;
            rptPosts.DataBind();
        }
    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Get the index of clicked row then get textbox control to get its value 
        // get row index for clicked button
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).CommandArgument);

        //get input string from textbox
        string inputString = ((TextBox)rptPosts.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2")).Text; 

        Response.Write(inputString);
    }
```

It's a simple way to get any properties inside your object.

Comment: Thanks for all but if you can to example i dont understand you.

Comment: I have updated the answer with repeater example, try it and feed me back if it you have any problems

Comment: where i can find that

Comment: where i can send the textbox in repeter

Comment: code updated to get the input value from textbox... 
testWebApp is my project namespace, replace it with yours

Comment: ok and the first way with for dont work becaue write me  cant comare string to int and if i change that that not work way can you help me

Comment: and if you know how to  send Textbox1,text in repeter to other page

Comment: where i can find my namespace

Comment: by this way you can send your Textbox1.Text to other pages, the idea is to get its value (which is done by code in answer) then you can send it... you don't need to append your namespace, it's importance is to define the Post object... could you please clarify your requirements ? you want to redirect the user to other pages with Textbox.Text on button click or wht ?